# Minimum of Frobenius norm

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm not sure if this solvable. I would like to find an orthogonal matrix that minimizes the following Frobenius norm: $$\min||BQ||^2 \\ \text{s.t. } Q^TQ=diag(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$$
where $\alpha_i=||q_i||$ and $q_i$ is the $ith$ column of $Q$, $Q$ is $N \times N$ and $B$ is $M \times N$. Note that the columns of Q are not orthonormal but orthogonal.

Comment: It would appear $B$ and the $\alpha$'s are given. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: $B$ is given, but $\alpha's$ are not, they are part of $Q$.

Comment: In that case, the minimum occurs with $Q=0.$

Comment: @WillJagy: Maybe you should convert your comment into a short answer?

Comment: Edit in a worked example. This is clear as mud.

Answer (score 1):

As you specify nothing about the $\alpha$'s, the minimum you are asking about occurs with $Q=0.$

Comment: I fail to see how $Q=0$ would give the minimum, I should have mentioned that $\alpha_i \neq 0$ so $Q$ can not be zero. $\alpha_i$ is actually the norm of $q_i$.

Comment: Well, you could edit your question, put in some examples with actual numbers, maybe 2 by 2 for $Q,$ give numbers for $B$ and show how you arrived at a solution to what you actually want.

Comment: @user63552, it still appears that you can take the $\alpha_i$ arbitrarily close to $0$ and thereby get $Q$ arbitrarily close to the $0$ matrix. In which case the minimum is not actually achieved. It happens.

Answer (score 0):

So, we would like to minimize $\mathrm{Trace}(Q^TB^TBQ)$ such that $Q^TQ=D$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix positive diagonal elements; i.e. the $\alpha_i$'s.

We have that $$\mathrm{Trace}(Q^TB^TBQ)=\mathrm{Trace}(B^TBQQ^T)=\sum_{i=1}^N\mathrm{Trace}(B^TBq_iq_i^T)=\sum_{i=1}^Nq_i^TB^TBq_i$$ and we have that $q_i^Tq_i=\alpha_i$, $i=1,\ldots,N$ and $q_i^Tq_j=0$, $i\ne j$.

Now we can use the fact that $B^TB$ is symmetric, so it has real nonnegative eigenvalues with orthonormal eigenvectors. So, it seems convenient to reformulate the expression as

$$\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i\tilde q_i^TB^TB\tilde q_i$$ and we have that $\tilde q_i^T\tilde q_i=1$, $i=1,\ldots,N$ and $\tilde q_i^T\tilde q_j=0$, $i\ne j$.

Now, let $(\lambda_i,v_i)$, $i=1,\ldots,N$, be the eigendecomposition of $B^TB$ such that $\lambda_1\ge\lambda_2\ge\ldots\ge\lambda_N$.

In the case where the $\alpha_i$'s are the same (i.e. $\alpha_i=\alpha$) it is immediate to see that the minimum is simply $\alpha\cdot\mathrm{trace}(B^TB)$. Otherwise, one can see that the optimization problem reduces to the combinatorial problem

$$\min_{\sigma\in S}\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_{\sigma(i)}\lambda_i$$

where $S$ is the set of permutations from $\{1,\ldots,N\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,N\}$. At optimality we would then have $\tilde q_{\sigma(i)}=v_i$ or, equivalently $q_{\sigma(i)}=\alpha_{\sigma(i)}^{1/2}v_i$.